# Prove that $|\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1-\cos(1/k))|\leq 2$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have an exercise to prove that $$|\sum_{k=1}^\infty(1-\cos(1/k))|\leq 2$$ but I have no idea where to start this proof. My first idea is to compare $1-\cos(1/k)$ to another sequence and conclude the previous statement, but I cannot come up with any sequences that would satisfy this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|1-\cos\frac1k|\leq\frac{1}{2k^2}$

Take the sum on both sides.

For a proof of the 1st statement, we have,
$1-\cos\frac1k=2\sin^2\frac{1}{2k}\leq\frac{1}{2k^2}$( As $\sin x\leq x$)

Comment: Then how do we show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2k^2}\leq 2$?

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is well known enough, you can simple quote it. Alternatively, one have $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} < 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k-1)} = 2$.

Comment: Prove by induction that $\sum_{1 \le k \le n} \frac{1}{k^1} \le 1 - \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Do you know where I could find a proof of the first statement? I have been looking for what p-series converge to but have not found anything.